# Update query when all fields are optional

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a table that I need to update where all columns are optionally passed to a method.

I am then using ColdFusion to check if each column was passed and to add it to the update query.

What is the best way to do this? I can't always update the user_id field because it is an identity field. Is there something similar to setting 1 = 1 like I have below that will work? The issue is just with the commas causing syntax errors.

Thanks for any help.

```
update users
set 1 = 1
    <cfif len(arguments.userType)>,user_type = #arguments.userType#</cfif>
    <cfif len(arguments.primaryGroupId)>,primary_group_id = #arguments.primaryGroupId#</cfif>
    <cfif len(arguments.email)>,email = '#arguments.email#'</cfif>
    <cfif len(arguments.password)>,password = '#arguments.password#'</cfif>
    <cfif len(arguments.firstName)>,first_name = '#arguments.firstName#'</cfif>
    <cfif len(arguments.lastName)>,last_name = '#arguments.lastName#'</cfif>
    <cfif len(arguments.status)>,status = '#arguments.status#'</cfif>
    <cfif len(arguments.languageId)>,language_id = #arguments.languageId#</cfif>
    <cfif len(arguments.gmtOffset)>,gmt_offset = '#arguments.gmtOffset#'</cfif>
where user_id = #arguments.userId#
```

Comment: Be sure to use <cfqueryparam>!!!

Comment: Can you add any columns to the table? If so adding a modifiedDate = sysdate instead of 1=1 would help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're updating, and the argument was not passed then just set it to the current value.

```
update users
set
    user_type = <cfif len(arguments.user_type)>#arguments.userType#<cfelse>user_type</cfif>
    ,primary_group_id = <cfif len(arguments.primaryGroupId)>#arguments.primaryGroupId#<cfelse>primary_group_id</cfif>
    ,email = <cfif len(arguments.email)>'#arguments.email#'<cfelse>email</cfif>
where user_id = #arguments.userId#
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... you can count off the number of updates you do. That would "Fix" the query above. As in:

```
<cfset updCt = false/>
<cfif len(arguments.usertype)>, user_type = #arguments.userType# 
    <cfset updCt = true/>
</cfif>
<cfif len(arguments.primaryGroupID)>
  <cfif updCt>,</cfif> 
    primary_group_id = #arguments.primaryGroupID# <cfset updCT = true/>
</cfif>
```

... you get the idea. Pretty messy though.  I think I would be more likely to insure that the arguments are all there - passing in unchanged values so the query is updating whole dataset (or whatever).

Comment: Too bad the table does not have auditing columns ie `LastUpdatedDate`, `LastUpdatedBy`. As that would solve the problem quite simply.

Comment: (Darn I hit submit too soon ..) If not, I prefer referencing the database column rather than passing in the original values as arguments. Just in case something changes after the data was first pulled. But it is the same idea :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can make all your arguments (other than the UserID) optional AND without a default value, then you can do something like:

```
<cffunction name="updateUser">
 <cfargument name="userID" required="true">

 <cfset argumentMap = {field1 = {name="field_1", type="cf_sql_varchar"},
                      field2 = {name="field_2", type="cf_sql_numeric"},
                      ....} />
 <!--- where field1, field2, etc will match the name 
       of the arguments to your function--->

 <cfif arrayLen(structKeyArray(arguments)) gt 1>
   <cfquery>
   UPDATE users
     SET
      <cfloop collection="#arguments#" item="arg">
         #argumentMap[arg].name# = <cfqueryparam 
                                       value="#arguments[arg]#"
                                       type="#argumentMap[arg].type#" />
      </cfloop>
     WHERE user_id = <Cfqueryparam value="#arguments.userID#" type="cf_sql_numeric"/>
   </cfquery>
 </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

This will only execute the UPDATE statement with the given arguments.